# GNU netcat exit code always 1?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, exit-code, netcat

I'm trying to use GNU variant of netcat in script but it *always* returns exit code 1 even if everything is fine. Here's my case step by step:

1. run `nc -l 127.0.0.1 -p 7000`
2. run `nc 127.0.0.1 7000`
3. press ctrl+c on client nc
4. server nc always returns 1

It makes me unable to detect socket bind error in bash script. Precisely it's GNU netcat from Arch linux. BSD netcat for Arch doesn't fail on socket bind error when address is in use so it's not much better either...

Comment: It seems that the client terminating is a good reason for the server to fail.  What happens if you use ctrl+d on the client?

Comment: On GNU netcat - nothing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After looking at the GNU Netcat source code, I have a bad news for you...

```
int c, glob_ret = EXIT_FAILURE;
```

The variable `glob_ret` is set to `EXIT_FAILURE` (1) and only changes in port scan mode or tunnel mode. The variable isn't set in listen mode, so the program will always exit with a 1 code.

You can take a look at the netcat.c source file here : https://pastebin.com/fh66BPgg (function `main`)